# html add cart, basket and checkout javascript

Tags: javascript

can you someone to fix add cart to basket and checkout. the shopping cart cant be add the item in to the basket the javascript show me null if i try to add. all codes i have been post. thank you in advance. 
cart.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart Pure Javascript</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<br>
<p id="demo"><table border="1|1"><tbody><tr><td>Product ID</td><td>Product Description</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Price</td><td>Action</td></tr><tr><td>GPS</td><td>Gps tracker</td><td>10</td><td>5</td><td><button type="submit" onclick='deleteProduct("GPS", this);'>Delete Item</button> &nbsp; <button type="submit" onclick='addCart("GPS", this);'>Add to Cart</button></td></tr><tr><td>Alarm</td><td>Alarm door</td><td>1</td><td>10</td><td><button type="submit" onclick='deleteProduct("Alarm", this);'>Delete Item</button> &nbsp; <button type="submit" onclick='addCart("Alarm", this);'>Add to Cart</button></td></tr><tr><td>Car</td><td>Toyota</td><td>1</td><td>200</td><td><button type="submit" onclick='deleteProduct("Car", this);'>Delete Item</button> &nbsp; <button type="submit" onclick='addCart("Car", this);'>Add to Cart</button></td></tr></tbody></table></p> <br>
<h2> Shopping Cart </h2>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<h2>Grand Total:</h2>
<p id="demo3"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

js.js page contain javascript code auto calculate add to cart and auto delete auto sum and more function but now it became null

```
var products = [];
    var cart = [];


        function deleteProduct(product_id, e) {
            e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                    // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
                    products.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            var productID = document.getElementById("productID").value;
            var product_desc = document.getElementById("product_desc").value;
            var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            var price = document.getElementById("price").value;

}
        function addCart(productID) {
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                    var cartItem = null;
                    for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                        if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {
                            cartItem = cart[k];
                            cart[k].product_qty++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (cartItem == null) {

                        var cartItem = {
                            product: products[i],
                            product_qty: products[i].product_qty 
                        };
                        cart.push(cartItem);
                    }
                }
            }

            renderCartTable();

        }

        function renderCartTable() {
        var html = '';
        var ele = document.getElementById("demo2");
        ele.innerHTML = ''; 

        html += "<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
        html += "<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
        html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
        html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
        html += "<td>Price</td>";
        html += "<td>Total</td>";
        html += "<td>Action</td></tr>";
        var GrandTotal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_id + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_desc + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + cart[i].product_qty + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_price + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty) + "</td>";
            html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Subtract Quantity</button> &nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='addQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Add Quantity</button> &nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='removeItem(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Remove Item</button></td>";
            html += "</tr>";

           GrandTotal += parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty);            

        }
        document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = GrandTotal;
        html += "</table>";
        ele.innerHTML = html;
    }


        function subtractQuantity(product_id)
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                    cart[i].product_qty--;
                }

                if (cart[i].product_qty == 0) {
                    cart.splice(i,1);
                }

            }
            renderCartTable();
        }
        function addQuantity(product_id)
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                    cart[i].product_qty++;
                }  
            }
            renderCartTable();
        }
        function removeItem(product_id)
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                    cart.splice(i,1);
                }

            }
            renderCartTable();
        }
```

why add cart not working? the java `null` me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the methods and try to debug it, all the methods are using the `products` array assuming it's filled with a json objects representing all the products.

So you should have (I did it for one product, fill the rest) :

```js
var products = [{product_id: 'GPS', product_price: 5}, ...];
```

You `addCart` method also had a typo : change `product_id` to `productID` to match the function params.

```js
        function addCart(productID) {
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == productID) {
                    var cartItem = null;
                    for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                        if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {
                            cartItem = cart[k];
                            cart[k].product_qty++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (cartItem == null) {

                        var cartItem = {
                            product: products[i],
                            product_qty: products[i].product_qty 
                        };
                        cart.push(cartItem);
                    }
                }
            }

            renderCartTable();
        }
```

Here is a working example to add the GPS product.

```js
var products = [{
    product_id: 'GPS',
    product_price: 5,
    product_desc: 'Gps tracker',
    product_qty: 1
}];
var cart = [];


function deleteProduct(product_id, e) {
    e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
            products.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

function addCart(productID) {
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == productID) {
            var cartItem = null;
            for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {
                    cartItem = cart[k];
                    cart[k].product_qty++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (cartItem == null) {

                var cartItem = {
                    product: products[i],
                    product_qty: products[i].product_qty
                };
                cart.push(cartItem);
            }
        }
    }

    renderCartTable();
}

function renderCartTable() {
    var html = '';
    var ele = document.getElementById("demo2");
    ele.innerHTML = '';

    html += "<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
    html += "<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
    html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
    html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
    html += "<td>Price</td>";
    html += "<td>Total</td>";
    html += "<td>Action</td></tr>";
    var GrandTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        html += "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_id + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_desc + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + cart[i].product_qty + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_price + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty) + "</td>";
        html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Subtract Quantity</button> &nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='addQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Add Quantity</button> &nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='removeItem(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Remove Item</button></td>";
        html += "</tr>";

        GrandTotal += parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty);

    }
    document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = GrandTotal;
    html += "</table>";
    ele.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart Pure Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo">
        <table border="1|1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product ID</td>
                    <td>Product Description</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>GPS</td>
                    <td>Gps tracker</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" onclick='deleteProduct("GPS", this);'>Delete Item</button> &nbsp;
                        <button type="submit" onclick='addCart("GPS", this);'>Add to Cart</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Alarm</td>
                    <td>Alarm door</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" onclick='deleteProduct("Alarm", this);'>Delete Item</button> &nbsp;
                        <button type="submit" onclick='addCart("Alarm", this);'>Add to Cart</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Car</td>
                    <td>Toyota</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" onclick='deleteProduct("Car", this);'>Delete Item</button> &nbsp;
                        <button type="submit" onclick='addCart("Car", this);'>Add to Cart</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </p>
    <h2> Shopping Cart </h2>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <h2>Grand Total:</h2>
    <p id="demo3"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is that possible `onclick="AddtoCart('GPS',5,'GPS Tracker',1)`  and `products` handle this?

Comment: yes you could do something like this : https://codepen.io/adrientiburce/pen/NWGazbJ?editors=1011

Comment: this is my original code https://codepen.io/henok400/pen/dyYVweX